# Bitrix, привязка URL к форме отправки данных

Tags: битрикс

Есть интернет-магазин на Bitrix.
У него есть в панели вкладки "Сервис - Веб-формы - Заявки на получение скидки".  Заявка на получение скидки - форма обратной связи, всплывающая по нажатию кнопки. Человек заполняет 3 поля, captcha и нажимает "отправить", в админке приходит заявка но БЕЗ указания страницы товара, который был запрошен на скидку. Я перерыла все настройки и не нашла нужной. Покопалась в руководстве и нашла лишь упоминание про

```
"SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => Array(
        "view" => "#RESULT_ID#/"
```

в просмотрах результатов, но такого файла на сервере не оказалось (что-то там про result он называется), так вот, подскажите, как можно реализовать прикрепление URL на товар, при запросе скидки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте поле для хранения URL товара.

Затем сделайте обработчик события onBeforeResultAdd в /bitrix/php_interface/init.php

В обработчике события - устанавливайте нужное значение из $APPLICATION->GetCurUri()

Описание события:
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/form/events/onbeforeresultadd.php

Примерный код:

```
function my_onBeforeResultAdd($WEB_FORM_ID, $arFields, $arrVALUES) {
  global $APPLICATION;

  if ($WEB_FORM_ID == #INSERT_FORM_ID#) {
    $arrVALUES['form_text_#INSERT_FIELD_ID#'] = $APPLICATION->GetCurUri();
  }
}
```